# Help with series: where to start?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve this exercise. It has been asked to study the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{nx^3}{n^2 +x^2}.$$

Honestly, I don't where to start. Could anyone please give me a hint? Then I'll try to post my personal solution.

Thank you in advance!

${\bf EDIT:}$ Having
$$f_n(x) = \frac{nx^3}{n^2 +x^2},$$
it is
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}f_n(x) =\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{nx^3}{n^2 +x^2}=0,$$
hence the series could converge. I would like to test the uniform convergence by using the ratio criterion (I don't know if it is the right choice in this case). I have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}|f_n(x)| =\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n|x|^3}{n^2 +x^2}.$$
By using the ratio criterion, it follows that
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{f_{n+1}(x)}{f_n(x)}=\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{(n+1)|x|^3}{(n+1)^2+ x^2}\cdot \frac{n^2+x^2}{n |x|^3}=\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{(1+1/n)(n^2+x^2)}{(n+1)^2 +x^2}=1,$$
so it is inconclusive.
Could anyone please validate my reasoning so far? Since the ratio test is inconclusive, how should I proceed?

Comment: If you have a personal solution it would be helpful if you could edit into the question.  You might want at least to tell us for which values of $x$ you think this converges to a finite number

Comment: Hint: $\sim\dfrac{x^3}n$.

Comment: $f(n) \to 0$ does not imply $\sum f(n)$ necessarily converges. You are summing over $n$ not $x$ as it seems $x$ remains constant

Comment: @Henry sorry, I mean "could". I edited.

Comment: Your computation for the ratio test is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_{n=1}^{m}\frac{nx^3}{n^2 +x^2} \, dn= \frac12 x^3 \log_e(x^2+m^2)-\frac12 x^3 \log_e(x^2+1)$$

Comment: I am sorry, how should I use your hint?

Comment: @User1010 You could try to use my hint to put a lower bound on the partial sums

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how.

Comment: @User1010 This is the [Integral Test](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralTest.aspx). What other tests for convergence or divergence do you know aside from the ones you have mentioned? There is more than one way to solve this problem.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you for the reference! If I take $m\to +\infty$ in the above integral thus, it diverges, so the series diverges, isn't it? It seems a very nice test! I also know the ratio test, the square test, the comparison test, but it seems the easiest one to apply here.

Comment: @User1010 The comparison test also works for this problem.

Comment: @DavidK could you please me understand how? I am not able to find  an upper bound here.

Comment: @User1010 I would call $x^2/n$ an "upper" bound, but that doesn't help. To show divergence you need something that is *less* than $nx^3/(n^2+x^2)$. I don't see a useful formula that works for all $n$, but you only need it to work for large $n$. For example, if it works for all $n > x$ it's good enough.

Comment: @DavidK I think my expression may be a lower bound, at least for positive $x$

Comment: The integral test and the comparison test are closely related. You could even say the integral test is a form of comparison test. So yes, the integral gives a lower bound.