# Help with series: a little extra difficulty

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I refer to this question [Help with series: where to start?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4145219/help-with-series-where-to-start/4145226?noredirect=1#comment8579330_4145226)
but with a little increase of difficulty. I would study the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\frac{nx^3}{n^2+x^2}.$$

Same reasons as in [Help with series: where to start?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4145219/help-with-series-where-to-start/4145226?noredirect=1#comment8579330_4145226), allow us to conclude that there is no uniform convergence. In particular, it makes no sense to study, for example, the total convergence since total convergence implies the uniforme convergence. The only thing that it makes sense (correct me if I am wrong) is to study the pointwise convergence.

In order to study the pointwise convergence, I use the Leibnitz criterion. I observe that, having
$$f_n(x)=\frac{nx^3}{n^2+x^2},$$
it is:

1)$\;\lim_{n\to +\infty} f_n(x)=0$;

2)$\;f_n(x)\ge 0\iff x\ge 0$;

3. $f_n(x)$ is always increasing (when $x>0$),

thus, if $x\ge 0$ the series thus not converge pointwise. My questions are: does my reasoning hold so far?
Moreover, what to say when $x<0$?

I hope someone could help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you think $f_n(x)$ is always increasing?  For $x<0$, note $f_n(-x)=-f_n(x)$.

Comment: I mean, it is always incresing when $x>0$. I edited.

Comment: Hint: alternating, decreasing series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 3 first statements are correct. Your conclusion *thus, if $x\ge 0$ the series thus not converge pointwise* is not correct.

To study pointwise convergence, you need to fix $n$ and look at the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n f_n(x)$. This is indeed convergent as we have here an alternating series as the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ is eventually decreasing (and positive) and converging to zero. And therefore you can apply (Leibnitz) [Alternating series test](http://Alternating%20series%20test).

Regarding $x \le 0$, you just have to notice that all the $f_n$ are odd maps.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am missing something. Why, if $x\ge 0$, it is decreasing?

Comment: @User1010 Just look at $f_n(x) - f_{n+1}(x)$.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still not convinced. Moreover, If I compute the first derivative of $f_n(x)$, it is always $\ge 0$, so $f_n(x)$ is always increasing.

Comment: The first derivative gives you the variation of $f$ as a function of $x$ while $n$ is fixed. This is not at all what you need! You need to fix $x$ and look at the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$... a completely different story!!! The derivative of $f$ with regard to $x$ is useless to study pointwise convergence.

Comment: Thank you for your crucial comment, I missed that! Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, just another comment. What about odd maps?

Comment: What do you mean by *What about odd maps?*

Comment: I mean, how can help to know that $f_n(x)$ is an odd mapp?

Comment: By definition you just have to verify that $f_n(-x)=-f_n(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$... which is trivial.

Comment: Yes, clear, but why it is important to know if $f_n(x)$ is odd or not? I could use some trick?

Comment: Based on the fact that the map is odd, it is trivial to prove that pointwise convergence for $x \ge 0$ implies pointwise convergence for $x \le 0$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw in your argument : for $x\geq 0$, the (non-zero) sequence $(f_n(x))_{n \in \mathbb N}$ cannot be non-negative and go to zero.

For any $x \in \mathbb R$, we have :

1. $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$
2. since :
   $$f_n(x) = \frac{x^3}{n + \frac{x^2}{n}}$$
   the sequence $(f_n(x))_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is either non-negative and (eventually) decreasing (when $x\geq 0$) or non-positive and (eventually)  increasing (when $x\leq 0$)

Therefore, by the Leibniz criterion, $\sum_n (-1)^n f_n(x)$ converges (pointwise) for every $x\in\mathbb R$.